# Loading module from “http://localhost/js/three.module.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”

Tags: javascript, json, mime-types

I am trying to use three.module.js but I'm having a big deal getting it to work die to the MIME type blocking, I'm using xampp as a local host (I set up xampp to allow .js types also as an attempt to solve the issue) but nothing seems to be working. the path seems correct, im hosting the files locally (tried linking to an online version too without success)

its even more confusing as OrbitControls.js does not seem to be blocked.

I tried the following:  set up xampp to allow .js types also as an attempt to solve the issue) but nothing seems to be working. the path seems correct, im hosting the files locally (tried linking to an online version too without success). expecting either edge or firefox to allow the .js file but nothing.

file architecture is
globe
|__globe.html
|__js
|__three.module.js
|__OrbitControls.js

CODE

```
// Import statements with paths relative to the root
import * as THREE from 'http://localhost/globe/js/three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from './OrbitControls.js';

// Scene setup
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000); // Black background

// Camera setup
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 5;

// Renderer setup
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Globe (sphere) setup
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xaaaaaa });
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

// Lighting setup
const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(5, 3, 5);
scene.add(light);

// OrbitControls setup
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// Render loop
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

Comment: If you were to check the Network tab of your browser's DevTools, is there a 404 status code next to `http://localhost/globe/js/three.module.js`? If there is, then your path for it is most likely wrong. If I understand your directory structure correctly, the two *.js files are in the same parent directory (`js`). If they are, what happens if you replace `http://localhost/globe/js/three.module.js` with `./three.module.js`?

Answer (score -1):

Install threejs in your project root:

```
npm i three
```

Import the module in your code

```
import * as THREE from “three”
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js'
```

You may need to bundle your code in order to run it (for example using `esbuild`) or set the script property `type=“module”`